# OData V3 exclude property

Tags: c#, linq, odata

I wish to exclude a particular property from a entity collection over odata.

I've used .Expand("Files") to retrieve that particular collection, they are files in the database and I want all of the metadata (like Name and MimeType) of the file, but not the binary body itself.

I am not allowed to change the OData service itself so if it's possible at all, it must be done using a instruction in the odata query.

Any thoughts? Thx in advance.

UPDATE2: Vagif has been helpful, but made me realize I did not phrase my question entirely correctly. Once again: apologies. The actual property can be in the class that is returned by expanding "Files", but it must be null. In other words: I'd like the expanded child records to have a property not being filled with data.

UPDATE: Thx nemesv. I should indeed have been more specific. The odata service is build using the odata nuget package using visual studio using c#. The client uses the same tools. The server however uses odata 5.0.1. The client any version I want, (5.6 now I think).

Comment: How do you call the odata service? Which library are using? Using the url syntax your query should look like this: `http://localhost/odata/YourThings?$expand=Files&$select=YourProp,Files/Name,Files/MimeType`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use C# and LINQ on the client side, you can select the properties you want to include in the payload using Select clause and anonymous types, e.g.:

var results = context.MyCollection.Select(x => new { x.Name, x.Category });

**UPDATE**

The trick with selecting columns from expanded entity is that you don't need to explicitly expand it: WCF Data Services LINQ provider fill figure it out. Here's an example using Northwind data model:

```
[Test]
public void SelectProductAndCategoryColumns()
{
    var result = _context.Products
        .Where(x => x.ProductID == 1)
        .Select(x => new { x.ProductID, x.Category.CategoryID, x.Category.CategoryName })
        .Single();
    Assert.AreEqual(1, result.ProductID);
    Assert.AreNotEqual(0, result.CategoryID);
    Assert.IsNotNull(0, result.CategoryName);
}
```

Note that I am chaining expanded columns in the Select clause without using Expand clause. And it works this way (but only for one level, you can't chain them further).

Comment: Sounds good, but how do I do that on an Expanded path?

var results = context.MyCollection.Expand("Files").Select(x => new { x.Name, x.Files.Name }); ?

Comment: @GerbenRampaart, I have updated my answer, hopefully it will help you building the right statement.

Comment: You've been a huge help so far, (particularly on the fact that I don't _have_ to use Expand in this scenario, I did not know that) but please note that my question was to exclude a property. This solution forces for to return an anonymous function breaking my syntax for my deferred chain. In other words, and taking your example, I'd like to exclude ONLY "CategoryName" (or lazy-load it, that doesn't matter). Because in my scenario, I'd like to lazy load my BLOB property, it mustn't include the bytes in the database record. (it's ok if the property is still there, but I'd like it to be null)

Comment: OData does not have a directive for excluding a particular properties, so including all but the one you don't need is the only way to implement what you're trying to achieve. You can read more about OData v3 protocol here: http://www.odata.org/documentation/odata-v3-documentation/url-conventions/